# On groups with finite pro-$p$ completion for all primes $p$

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Say that a group has Property X if its pro-$p$-completion is finite for every prime $p$. For instance, every perfect group has Property X.

> Is there a finitely generated, residually finite group $G$ such that every finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is either virtually nilpotent, or has Property X (but $G$ is not virtually nilpotent)? Furthermore, is there such $G$ with intermediate growth?

We would like to have examples where not much is known about their word growth.

Motivation: Henry Bradford and I found some lower bound on the word growth for some groups. We are looking for examples of groups for which this will be useful.

**Edit**: I changed the condition on the subgroups to subgroups who do not have polynomial word growth to avoid the lower bound $e^{\sqrt{n}}$ that follows from a result of Grigorchuk, see Theorem E.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07044.pdf.

**Edit**: see [Groups with unknown word growth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288509/groups-with-unknown-word-growth) for a refinement of this question.

Comment: Such groups do not exist. Indeed the trivial subgroup and, moreover,  any cyclic subgroup does not satisfy one of your conditions.

Comment: @MarkSapir thanks. I have fixed it (I hope).

Comment: To answer the question in the title: any perfect finitely generated infinite residually finite group works (since it's perfect, its pro-$p$-completion is trivial, while its profinite completion is infinite). For instance $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is such a group.

Comment: This is distinct to the question in the text (at this very time), since it refers to subgroups of $p$-power index. The core of a subgroup of $p$-power index is often far from being of $p$-power index. For instance, the product $\prod_n\mathrm{Alt}_{p^n}$ admits subgroups of arbitrary large $p$-power index, and hence so do its dense subgroups.

Comment: I would have been reasonable to ask the question in the title, and to require in addition that it holds for all subgroups of finite index (to discard examples such as $\mathrm{SL}_d(\mathbf{Z})$. Requiring something about all non-cyclic subgroups strongly narrows the scope (you forbid free subgroups, etc).

Comment: The point is that if the group contains, for example, a non abelian free groups, then its word growth is already exponential.

Comment: Yiftach, there are several problems making your question unclear, which you didn't fix; please clarify: (1) the title is confusing since it suggest another easier question (2) you're talking of subgroups of $p$-power index, but most likely you mean normal subgroups of $p$-power index.

Comment: Also beware that Bartholdi's Theorem E2 is most likely miswritten. Indeed for a f.g. group, "residually virtually nilpotent" is equivalent to "residually finite" (since virtually nilpotent f.g. groups are residually finite, and finite groups are residually nilpotent). But I don't expect its sentence starting with "In particular, if $G$ is residually virtually nilpotent... blah" to be known to hold (as it would assert a gap between polynomial and $e^{\sqrt{n}}$ for residually finite fg groups). It's probably meant to hold when $G$ is virtually residually nilpotent.

Comment: ... eventually I edited the question for clarification. I think it reflects the OP's request.

Comment: @YCor thanks a lot. It was a bit tricky to formulate this question.